# PostGIS data model design, multiple Geometry type in one field of one table VS separate table for each Geometry

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, gis, postgis

I am learning the database design, and particular the GIS database design for my GIS program.
The program needs to use multiple Geometry type, namely Point, LineString, and Polygon.

The problem I am facing is whether I should design a table that contains generic Geometry type or separate table for each Geometry. Almost exactly as this question from [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86273/homogeneous-vs-heterogeneous-schema-in-postgis)

However, I would be very appreciate to know the pros and cons for each design. And what would be considerations to take when designing them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: don't use generic geometry tables (imho).

This sort of question will get the Definitive Computer Programming Answer: "It depends on what you want to do with it."

Generally in database design we tend to model things, and put things of one type in one table and things of another type in a different table.  e.g. you have a Contact in one table and an Order that the contact might have made in another.

That extends to GIS things too.  Put the objects of the same type together and give them the type of geometry field that makes sense.   Usually it doesn't make sense for the same sort of thing to be defined in different ways.  If you want a property, you probably want polygon (or multi-polygon).  If you specifically want property boundaries, you probably want linestring.

Trying to allow the same thing to be defined in different ways makes using that data much harder.  For example, if you were to say "oh, it can be a boundary or a polygon, we don't mind" getting PostGIS to work with it will be harder.

Probably a key input to your decision is that there are a lot of PostGIS features that break if you feed them geometries of different types. For example if you have a particular row and it has a polygon, and you want to find out which other rows have a geometry that intersects with it, you could use `ST_INTERSECTS`, but that'll probably not do what you want if you have mixed geometries.